# CSS3 blur filter on image expands beyond original width

Tags: css

I am applying CSS3 blur filter on an image, but unexpectedly the blur effect goes out of the image original size (at least on Webkit browsers ).
I used `overflow: hidden;` but it's not working.
Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='img.jpg' class='blur' />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
.blur{
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);    
}

.container {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    margin:40px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33yu7619/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By giving the `img` a negative `margin` such as

```
img {
    margin: -5px;
}
```

... will hide the spillage. You can play around with the `margin`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/33yu7619/2/)

EDIT: Why This Occurs

Applying [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)...  you are blending your element by whatever amount of `px`, `em` etc. you declare e.g. `5px`. To create this blur, the element will be expanded/feathured by that amount outside of its current size.

So applying a negative margin essentially "clips" the size and prevents anything outside of it to work. "Clipping" it is one approach, another would be by wrapping the element with a `div` and declaring a `height` and `width` and applying `overflow: hidden`. This will mask the overflow.

Comment: This could be the best answer, but what is the logical explanation for this ?

Comment: Added a brief explanation

Comment: Your solution is a THEORY, but it doesn't work in Chrome.
The element blurred seems to be the ALREADY clipped element, not the whole element "inside" your overflow.

This fiddle shows a clip doesn't hide the blur but rather defines a new smaller element to be blurred, and that the idea of a children element "inside" or "behind" its parent, it's in your mind. Not the actual case. So the blurred effect spills over elements we "believe" they are behind (z-index) http://jsfiddle.net/5wz9w8o0/

Answer (score 1):

As I was experiencing the exact same bug on Safari 8 I thought I'd post my solution.

In the above example, you'd just need to add

```
-webkit-filter:blur(0px);
```

to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Put `height` and `width` attributes that are smaller than the image on the container. A size of 1px less than the image seems to work well.

CSS:

```
.container {
    /* ... */
    width:399px;
    height: 223px;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfh90svk/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The *blur effect* always go beyond the `width`.

In your case you can fix the issue using one of the following techniques -

1. Try setting a `width` of your `.container` and reduce **15px + 15px** from both height and width of the `img` using CSS **calc()** function.
2. Or you can just add a `padding` of **15px** to the `img`

[**DEMO** of 2nd solution](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/33yu7619/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about "blur" yet, but I'm guessing it spreads / blurs out the edges 15px (in this case) in every direction.  When you add padding: 15px; to your .container class it looks fine:

```
.container {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    margin:40px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33yu7619/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If your background around the clipping box .outer can be solid, you can cheat with a drop shadow. http://jsfiddle.net/ffghjkbj/

```
.overflow{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    margin: 30px;
}
.overflow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2 , 1.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.overflow:hover .inner{
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);

}
```

If you background is not solid, you could maybe use a border-image, with the same image than the background, to fake the effect, which would be almost the same than using a png mask with a hole in the middle, instead of a background, and moving the pseudo-object with the mask to the front with z-index.

The blurry border you see is generated by the .inner element being CLIPPED (by its parent) BEFORE the blur is applied. Definitely a way for the acceleration not to waste power in rendering hidden areas.

So the .inner element is ALREADY clipped at the parent's edges when the blur is applied to it, and the blurry frame is actualy the outside empty area bleeding inside the image when blurred. The blur is NOT applied to the whole inner element as we would imagine if the element was "inside" or "behind". Just to the visible part. (This is why an oversized .inner element as suggested above won't work).

It's not obvious because the idea of a children element "inside" or "behind" its parent is in our mind. Objects just happen to be clipped at the paren't coordinates, but are actually IN FRONT of the parent.